# Does this message from the Fire Department suggest the fire suppression and/or alarm system may be sufficiently faulty to endanger life and property?

Tags: alarm, fire

Does this message from the Fire Department pasted on the main fire control panel of my apartment building suggest that the fire suppression sprinklers and/or fire detection and/or alarm system may be sufficiently faulty to endanger life and property?

I called the local Fire Dept and they suggested even without paying heed to these details that the issues may be related to the alarm system per se, rather than matters directly under their purview.

I'm very nervous that the fire detection, or fire alarm or fire suppression systems or some combination thereof may be compromised, and that management is dragging its feet to fix it quickly and comprehensively.

Most recently, thunderstorm caused a false alarm, and the fire alarm (sound) could not be switched for for 20+ minutes. Could that delay be a symptom of the issues listed on this note?

In the past, I have noticed this same panel have flashing LED lights and a constant beeping sound - not any more though.

If you have the appropriate expertise and experience could you please interpret this note and also suggest what remedial actions the property management should be advised to take? If you will need more info to help answer my questions, please let me know how I can help you help me. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: It's an intriguing question, but it's quite a stretch to consider this DIY. In any case your building has (at least) two fire alarm panels; I think the note was left by the building maintenance person who struggled to figure out how to reset the alarm last time. It has nothing to do with the fire sprinklers, and does not (on its own) imply any sort of defect or degredation in alarm system function.

Comment: There is no implication whatever that the system is faulty or presents a life safety risk. There's a clear indication that resetting the alarms is a process requiring specific steps in specific order, which are detailed here for ease of servicing when a reset is required, that's all.

Comment: That sign looks new, and is probably a direct result of the recent event you described in paragraph 4.  Lessons were learned, and they were stuck on that note. I would maybe help them turn that into a placard. "I'm very nervous" Yeah, humans who don't analyze risk for a living *super suck* at analyzing risk. They are terrified to fly yet hop in a car without a second thought. Yes, bad fires have happened (Grenfell Towers) but buildings with internal sprinklers rarely have problems.  Get better at risk assessment.

Answer (score 6):

That message is most likely NOT from the Fire Department.

You should ask this question of the building management.

While I cannot guarantee the intent, it appears that the message is there in regard to resetting the alarm, should it go off.  It refers to proper procedure, rather than being critical of the performance of the system.

You may be over reacting a bit.